# Ajax file Upload Control (Asp.net 4.0)

Tags: ajax

I am developing a website in asp.net. On a page i have placed 5 Ajax File Upload control.
But i am unable to get the "filename" of the uploaded file in each control. 
Please help me
Thanks In Advance......

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file name in the UploadComplete event fired when the file upload is completed.

Example:

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = MapPath("~/upload/") + Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
    AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);

}
```

Reference here: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx